# Direction of force of surface tension

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, surface-tension

On the case (i) , the force of surface tension acts in both sides . In case (ii) , the force acts upwards . In case (iii) , the plane surface of a liquid drop is curved where force acts downwards...

What would be the direction of surface tension in the case (iv) ? I’ve shown the direction , but I’m not sure if it ...

[image]

Comment: What is (iv) supposed to be?

Comment: Isn't Ⅳ a rectangular box ...?

Comment: But where is the liquid surface?

Comment: @JohnRennie..Haha , the user drew some streamlines ..

Comment: @JohnRennie I've the same question what will be the direction of this force for a block immersed in water while drawing the free body diagram where can we show this force?

Answer (score 2):

The surface tension is due to an increase in potential energy with an increase in surface area. It is defined as the increase of energy per unit area. Thus a force is exerted against any deformation that tries to increase the surface area of the liquid. On the other hand, this force tries to minimize the surface area of any liquid.

Answer (score 0):

I think the force of surface tension is always tangent to the surface, so in case (iv) I will say the actual direction should depend on what material the block is made of and its weight; it could be any out of (i), (ii), and (iii), but what you have shown is unlikely.

Comment: You should have written it in the comment section.

Comment: @NehalSamee I disagree. Partial answers should be posted as answers, not as comments. We could discuss further on [meta] or in [chat] if you like.